# how filter filename if not include 01.jpg from multi sub directory

Tags: python, filter, directory, filenames

i have directory structure like 
images include dir_one、dir_two

dir_one not include any directory

dir_two include dir_three

dir_three not include any directory

dir_one include 01.jpg、02.jpg

dir_two include 02.jpg、03.jpg

dir_three include 02.jpg、03.jpg、04.jpg

i want get a list about dir path ,if dir
not include 01.jpg
will append to a list, then i will convert to a json file

```
    import json
import os
def file_name(file_dir):
    L=[]
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(file_dir):
        for file in filenames :
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.jpg':
                L.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
    return L

file_dir = 'F:\\tmp\\images'
files_list=file_name(file_dir)

item_list = set()
for item in files_list:
    print(item[-6:])
    index_of_dir_path = item.rfind('\\')
    filter_str='01.jpg'
    # if filter_str not in files_list:
    if filter_str not in item:
        item_list.add(item[0:index_of_dir_path])

json_data = {
    "dirPath_not_include_01_jpg_file":list(item_list)
}
target_json_path='out.json'
with open(target_json_path, 'w') as f:
    json_dumps = json.dumps(json_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    f.write(json_dumps)
```

i hope to make a json file like not include dir_one item path (cause dir_one include 01.jpg)

```
{
  "dirPath_not_include_01_jpg_file": [
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_two\\dir_three",
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_four",
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_five",
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_two"
  ]
}
```

but not code will include dir_one item path

```
{
  "dirPath_not_include_01_jpg_file": [
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_two\\dir_three",
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_one",
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_four",
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_five",
    "F:\\tmp\\images\\dir_two"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `item_list` outside the `for` loop; otherwise its previous value gets overwritten with each iteration. You should also make `item_list` a set instead so that if there are multiple `.jpg` files under the same directory they won't result in duplicate directories in the list:

```
item_list=set()
for item in files_list:
    print(item)
    index_of_dir_path = item.rfind('\\')
    print(item[0:index_of_dir_path])
    item_list.add(item[0:index_of_dir_path])
json_data = {
    "dirPath_not_include_01_jpg_file":list(item_list)
}
```

If you want to exclude directories containing `01.jpg` you should also check it before you add the files to the list:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(file_dir):
    if all('01.jpg' not in file for file in filenames):
        for file in filenames :
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.jpg':
                L.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
```

Comment: Oh My God !!  blhsing you so excellent !! Thank you My Dear Friend

Comment: is anyway to remove duplicate item?

Comment: You can use a `set` instead, and then convert it back to list when adding to `json_data`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanj you again , actually i lose to add my key problem code that is find dir full path not include '01.jpg' , i also update my question again

Comment: Simply change `if filter_str not in files_list:` to `if filter_str not in item:`.

Comment: it seems not work  (i also update question code)  i also try  change code  to   "if filter_str not in item[-6:]:"

Comment: That's because you also have other `.jpg` files in the same directory. Please see my updated answer.